# Can't log into any of the stack overflow sites anymore - no openid endpoint found

Tags: support, openid

It looks like I previously created my accounts using the URL to my blog - which used to be on blogger. Now it's on wordpress. I don't know if that's the problem or not but I can't log in anymore. I enter the URL to my blog and it tells me:

Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:  No OpenID endpoint found.

I tried telling it to recover my information but it just sends me an email that says:

You have the following OpenIDs associated with your Stack Overflow Careers account: (it just gives me the same URL I've already been entering)

How do I log in to my accounts now?

Comment: Other posts about "No OpenID endpoint found": http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22No+OpenID+endpoint+found%22